# Simple Jquery function to insert a query in database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

how do i put this SQL statment in a simple jquery function that whenever i call this function i insert a file in the databse

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages (sender, receiver, audioclip) VALUES ('$id', '3', '$audio_rand')")
```

Thank you

Comment: You would make an ajax call to a php script that does it. Check out [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 3):

You can't call SQL from jQuery: jQuery is a client-side language, while your database is server-side. You can use jQuery's [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method to send data back to the server. Whatever language you use there (I'm assuming from your tags you are using PHP) will call the SQL and update the database.

Comment: i have this function 

`$('#send').click(function(){
                    $.jRecorder.sendData();

                  })`

its related to a button send file once its recorded, i want it also on click to insert a query to databse, anyone ?

Comment: Sorry @rami987597, javascript in a browser just can't call SQL directly. It must be done server-side.

Comment: Use ajax. $('#send').click(function(){ $.jRecorder.sendData(); $.ajax({..})})